# Jquery overlay adds an extra unwanted img tag

Tags: jquery, overlay

I've created an overlay using JQuery. It works just fine in all browsers, however IE is rendering an extra, oversized border which I am not able to control with css. Upon further investigation using IE developer toolbar there appears to be an image tag generated which has in-line style in the tag:

My questions are: 
1. Is this image tag generated by jQuery but all other browsers know how to handle it? 
2. How is the rendering of this image controllable in IE if jQuery is responsible?

Here's the overlay div. Very simple:

```
<div class="modal" id="addCategoryPrompt">
    <p>Add Category</p>
</div>
```

Here's the link that invokes the overlay:

```
<a href="#" class="modalInput" rel="#addCategoryPrompt">Add Category</a>
```

Here's the Jquery:

```
$(".modalInput").overlay({
    mask: '#000',
    effect: 'apple',
    closeOnEsc : true,
    api:true,
    closeOnClick: false
});
```

Comment: How are you generating the overlay? Did you create it or is it a plugin? Could you show us your jQuery?

Comment: Added the code sample above.

Comment: Okay, at least I found what was causing the issue. It was the line “effect: 'apple'". After removing that the problem went away, although the effects did too, but I can live with that.